# Simple perchance beginner question: Randomizing starting option on a dropdown?

Tags: html

Below I have a small segment of script to create a dropdown for a hobbyist/casual project I'm working on.  The problem is that I want to increase randomization, but as it's written the dropdown always starts at Alpha. Ideally, I'd like to be able to have it start at a random position to reduce but not eliminate user choice in selecting an option. (The core of the project is to semi-randomly generate tasks to be completed in a game.  I tried a random option but that's beyond me.)

When I say 'problem,' I acknowledge that it is the smallest of possible issues, but I really have no idea what I'm doing.  I've done a fair amount of googling, but as I've essentially just reverse engineered this from another code segment, I can't honestly say that I don't fully understand it.  I am not a programmer, or even a student. So I am humbly asking for help as a layman. Even some tips in the right direction would be nice, since I don't even really know what terms to search for when I AM googling, except for code terms within the sample.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<select oninput="license = this.value, update()">
    <option value="A">Alpha</option>
  <option value="B">Bravo</option>
    <option value="C">Charlie</option>
    <option value="D">Delta</option>
    <option value="E">Echo</option>
  <option value="F">Foxtrot</option>
    <option value="G">Golf</option>
    <option value="H">Hotel</option>
  <option value="I">India</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What would you like? That, when launched, a random value (option) from the presented ones was displayed in the select?

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly it.  Sorry if I worded the question poorly.

Comment: Hi. I gave you a solution. If my solution helped you, mark it as solved by checking the box to the left of my solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short and correct solution to a random choice of `option`.

The logic of the random choice of the option is wrapped in the window load event:

```
window.onload = function() {
   ...
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let select = document.querySelector('select');
  let option = document.querySelectorAll('option');
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * option.length);
  select.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="A">Alpha</option>
  <option value="B">Bravo</option>
  <option value="C">Charlie</option>
  <option value="D">Delta</option>
  <option value="E">Echo</option>
  <option value="F">Foxtrot</option>
  <option value="G">Golf</option>
  <option value="H">Hotel</option>
  <option value="I">India</option>
</select>
```